# Python Requests Put not working with build.phonegap.com

Tags: python, cordova, python-requests, phonegap-build

I am making a python build script for a phonegap project. 
I need to open the ios key before i build
I am trying to do this with a http put request through the requests module for python.

If i do it with cURL from command line, it works fine

```bash
curl -vvv -d 'data={"password":"myPassWord"}' -X PUT https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/ios/193686?auth_token=passwordlesstokenphg
```

But from python like this.

```python
password_for_key = {'password': 'myPassword'}
authentication_token = {'auth_token': 'passwordlesstokenphg'}
requests.put('https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/ios/193686', data=password_for_key, params=authentication_token)
```

It just returns the json you would recieve if you did a cURL without the data. 
For me it seems like the data is not being sent to phonegap correctly.

API reference from build.phonegap.com
[docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/developer_api_write.md.html](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/developer_api_write.md.html)

Please help :)

Comment: Is the data you are passing with `curl` really `data={"password":"myPassWord"}`? This is different from what you are sending with Python. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you do

```
curl -d "..." -X PUT https://example.com
```

curl sends exactly what's in that string. requests does not translate so directly to curl. To do something similar in requests you need to do the following:

```
import json

password_for_key = {'password': 'myPassword'}
authentication_token = {'auth_token': 'passwordlesstokenphg'}

requests.put('https://build.phonegap.com/api/v1/keys/ios/193686',
             data={'data': json.dumps(password_for_key)},
             params=authentication_token)
```

What requests will do is build `data={"password":"myPassword"}` for you if you use the above. First you have to JSON encode the data in `password_for_key` then pass it in the dictionary to `data`.

Comment: I wanted to add a missing comma after the URL but stackoverflow only allows me to do 6 character edits only.

Comment: Ah sorry about that @RasmusØstergaardKjærVoss